# Non standard sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select items with defined idBook from `exemplar` table which are currently not ordered(booked)- dateReturn field in **"orders"** table is not null.

Table `orders` can contain previously fulfilled orders with the same idExemplar!

If exemplar **has at least one record in "orders" table with dateReturned=null** then this exemplar should be excluded!

#### I've tried to use this query:

```
select * 
from exemplar 
join orders on orders.idExemplar=exemplar.idExemplar
where dateReturned is not null
```

but it gives wrong result if table orders contains previusly fulfilled orders with the same idExemplar

Comment: Why didn't you say that on the question I only just answered for you? could have pulled that into the solution for you.

Comment: Can u be a bit clear, you are telling that the dateReturned column is not null but u need to find rows having dateReturned= null.

Comment: rows from the 'exemplar' table which have non-null dateReturned shouldn't be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [@vizier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667766/297408), but expressed differently:

1) Using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM exemplar
WHERE idExemplar NOT IN (SELECT idExemplar FROM orders WHERE dateReturned IS NULL)
```

2) Using `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM exemplar e
LEFT JOIN ON orders o ON e.idExemplar = o.idExemplar AND o.dateReturned IS NULL
WHERE o.idExemplar IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If I undersand the problem correctly, this should do the trick:

```
select * 
from exemplar 
where not exists 
  ( select * 
    from orders 
    where orders.idExemplar=exemplar.idExemplar 
    and dateReturned is null )
```

Comment: Yup, probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal time to learn about outer joins:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html is one of my favorite examples

```
SELECT * 
FROM exemplar 
LEFT JOIN orders 
  on orders.idExemplar=exemplar.idExemplar 
WHERE dateReturned is null
```

Bit confused on the double nots... but since you said, "If exemplar has at least one record in "orders" table with dateReturned=null then this exemplar should be excluded!"
I would think you want where dateReturned IS NULL

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of exemplars where with a null order dateReturned order, where the idExemplar only has one row in orders

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM exemplar e 
INNER JOIN orders o
ON e.idExemplar = o.idExemplar
WHERE 
o.idExemplar IN ( 
    SELECT o.idExemplar FROM orders o 
    GROUP BY o.idExemplar 
    HAVING COUNT(o.idExemplar) = 1
) AND o.dateReturned IS NULL
```

This uses a sub query in the `where` clause to check if the current order idExemplars is in the set of unique idExemplars. It does this by counting the instances of each idExemplar and discarding any that appear more than once.

Comment: It says at least one, so should very likely be changed to >= :)